# Redux Framwork Global Variable in plugin

Tags: wordpress, redux-framework

I am currently developing a plugin which uses filters from redux framework. This plugin will be used by themes that uses Redux Framework to extend the functionality.

Filter i need to use is redux/validate/{opt_name}/defaults. Since it will be used by different themes, i am not able to get {opt_name} variable used by the theme. How can i get opt_name variable which will work for redux framework based themes ?

```
    if (class_exists( 'Redux' ) ) { 
        global $opt_name;
        add_filter('redux/validate/'.$opt_name.'/defaults', 
        'my_function_here' ); 
    }
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you show what you have tried

Comment: I tired making $opt_name global. But that work for few themes and not all.

Comment: Code samples please

Comment: This is what i have done.

if (class_exists( 'Redux' ) ) {
  global $opt_name;
  add_filter('redux/validate/'.$opt_name.'/defaults', 'my_function_here' );
}